# Is it ethical to enjoy old movies with racist/stereotypical content?

Tags: virtue-ethics, racism

Several old movies nowadays have misused and stereotypicalized many aspects of different cultures, genders, and races, like "Dumbo" with talking crows, who are voices in a caricature of African American dialect, or "Tropic Thunder". Is it ehtical to still watch these movies, which are considered American classics, and enjoy them?

Comment: Tropic thunder isn't an old movie. It's approximately as offensive today as it was when it came out, and in my completely subjective personal experience, the group that it should offend - black people - for the most part think it's funny and realise that they are not the butt of the joke.

Comment: Violence in movies, violent disturbing lyrics in pop music. The same questions have been asked in the past. Is it ethical to enjoy this type of entertainment? Does enjoyment of this type of entertainment lead to unethical behavior? Are people who enjoy violent movies more likely to commit violence. There is as much psychology in this as there is philosophy. Does enjoying Dumbo make one more likely to be racist?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends. For example, if you were to relish watching old movies precisely because you revelled in the kind of discrimination they displayed, then that would not be considered ethical. On the other hand, if you watched them for other reasons, and considered the racism to be an instructive example of what was wrong with society in those days, then that might not be considered unethical.

Answer (score 1):

I think [Jacqueline Stewart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacqueline_Stewart), a well-known scholar of black cinema, has a useful take on this.

She's quoted on [a KCRW radio page](https://www.kcrw.com/news/shows/press-play-with-madeleine-brand/social-media-fema-lamb-film-macarthur-genius/jacqueline-stewart-academy-museum-racist-films):

> Stewart argues that films like “Gone With The Wind” and “Breakfast at Tiffany’s” should be available because they’re undeniable evidence of the oppressive and stereotypical treatment of people of color in film. She also recalls the racist treatment of Hattie McDaniel (the first Black person to win an Oscar for her role in “Gone with the Wind”) at the 1940 Academy Awards. After receiving her award, she was escorted to a back table due to the venue’s segregationist policies.
>
> “If we suppress them because they're painful or problematic, then we also can't call Hollywood to task for these histories. … I think that it's really important to have the evidence of Hollywood's mistreatment of Black people both on screen and off screen, and to try to understand what [McDaniel’s] experience was like, and to look at the work that she did in the context of these really humiliating dehumanizing conditions.
>
> She adds, “I completely respect anyone's decision not to watch these films. But at the same time, I think that it would be more problematic if we tried to hide them away, or if we didn't try to develop the critical tools to understand how they worked, and how they continue to work in our society.”

In short, we should absolutely watch (and engage critically) with important but offensive films of the past if we are inclined to do so. As she also says in the embedded video: **"You can love something through critiquing it."**

Comment: Yes, but is it ethical to enjoy them?

Comment: @Lukiius: I thought that was clear enough: it depends how. I made a small edit after your comment to emphasize this.